# How to purge unmanaged NFS mounts in Puppet?

Tags: nfs, puppet

How can I purge all unmanaged NFS mounts with Puppet?

Example 1: The following Puppet code purges all users not explicitly managed by Puppet:

```
resources { "user":
  purge => true,
}
```

Example 2: The following code purges all unmanaged Nginx virtual hosts:

```
file { "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/":
  recurse => true,
  purge => true,
}
```

But how can I purge all unmanaged NFS mounts?

Here's what I tried. I have my own definition for NFS mounts:

```
define nfs-client::mount() {
...
}
```

However, the following did not work:

```
resources { "nfs-client::mount":
  purge => true,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on this [bug report](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7600) I don't believe that this works on defines (which are collections of resources) - only types (built in or custom) that have an initialize() method implemented (these are individual resources).

However, as "[mount](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#mount)" is a built in resource, you should be able to just do:

```
resources{'mount': purge => true}
```

Comment: Lee, I actually ran this earlier with --noop and it had scary results (glad it was running noop). It would unmount all sorts of file mounts. I definitely want to remove only unmanaged NFS mounts, not unmanaged mounts of any type.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, and I should have realized that. I don't think there is a good way at present, unless you used the above, and made all the normal mounts managed mounts, which probably isn't very feasible.